# Sonarqube manual measures at file level

Tags: c++, c, plugins, sonarqube, asp.net-web-api

I'm using sonarqube for several C/C++ projects for which I use the C++ community plugin. Right now I have managed to get it working with cppncss and cppcheck. However, I need to also be able to parse the xml result file from CCCC (http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccc/). Currently what I'm doing is using the Web API provided by Sonar to create custom metrics and insert the global measures via a script(http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743270). The problem is that I also need to parse the results at file or component level, and I have looked in several places but I'm not sure if this is possible using only the Web API. I think another option would be to try to modify the C++ plugin so I can use the CCCC report directly, but the problem is I don't have any experience with Java and I'm not sure which steps should I take, or what should be modified from the plugin. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual measures are not the right way to add measures coming from external tools.
You should definitely modify the plugin.